# Fetch a valid url gives 404 error in node express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, fetch, http-status-code-404

I am trying to build web app using MEAN stack but there is a problem with get request.

```
app.route("/api/item/", function (req, res) {
    fetch("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.1.1/data/en_US/item.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.send({ data });
            // console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

This is API that simply fetches the url and get json file. I checked the url by using the url to chrome and I could see json data.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
};

  getitem(): Observable<Item> {
    return this.http.get<Item>('http://localhost:8000/api/item/', httpOptions);
  }
```

And I called the API in service.ts

```
this.shservice.getitem().subscribe(im => {
      this.item = im;
    });
```

And subscribe it in component.ts

Since I could manually access to the url and see json data, I thought there would be no problem but it kept on giving me 404 NOT FOUND error. It is quite simple implementation, so it is even harder to find which part is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your CORS in Node rather than from the Client ?